# How to make my UserForm code change the output cell of the code every time I run said UserForm in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have researched the web but can't find the solution that helps me.

I have a Excel Sheet and have created a UserForm that has a InkPicture Box and is set to allow a person to open the user form and draw their signature. There is a CommandButton assigned to take the signature and save it from the clipboard onto the PC. I Have another CommandButton assigned to retrieve said saved picture from the PC path and bring it back to a specific sheet in my workbook and insert it at a specific cell.

My need is the following:
I need the Code I'm using to update what cell it will insert the image at every time I click on the button. (In other words. I need the code to go from C3 to C50 on one digit increase every time I push the button and after it reaches revert back to C3)

Can this be done?

This code brings the image back to my sheet but every time the CommandButton is clicked the image gets inserted in C3(therefore all images are on top of each other as opposed to below each other):

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ImgPath As String
Dim W As Double, H As Double
Dim L As Long, T As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mobile POS Log Sheet")

'~~> This is my current pic file path
ImgPath = "C:\Users\raphaelo\Downloads\test.gif"

With ws
    W = 30                  '<~~ Width
    H = 11                  '<~~ Height
    L = .Range("c3").Left   '<~~ This is what should be changing each time I run the command
    T = .Range("c3").Top    '<~~ This is what should be changing each time I run the command
     '<~~ Both the L and T Range entries should change to the next cell (C3 to C4 to C5 and so on) One digit up every time I run the Command Code
     '<~~ Unless it's the Placement entry below?
    With .Pictures.Insert(ImgPath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = W
            .Height = H
        End With
        .Left = L
        .Top = T
        .Placement = 1 '<~~ Not sure if this is the one that should change one digit up each time I run the Command instead?
    End With
End With
```

Please guide me in the right direction! What would be the code that automatically re-calculates itself to assign the Output to a different cell in a column every time it's ran?

Comment: I would try to find the last used row on the sheet, add 1 or 50 to that number (however many rows you need) and paste it there.  Search find last used row in column.  Put the lastUsedRow in a variable, and change your code to L = .Range("c" & lastUsedRow + 50).Left   and T = .Range("c" + 50).Top

Comment: This sound like it would work!! I apologize i'm fairly new to VBA. Would it be to much to ask to give this to me in the way I should add it exactly? Could you use my current code and put the added code you are suggesting? Thank you (I will try to figure out based on what you already commented on how and where to add this.

Comment: This is what I added to my code based on what you suggested:
   After this line:  Dim L As Long, T As Long
    `Dim lastUsedRow As Variant`
And changed Ranges to:
    `With ws`
        `W = 30`                  '<~~ Width
       ` H = 11`                  '<~~ Height
        `L = .Range("c" & lastUsedRow + 50).Left`   '<~~ Left Position for image
        `T = .Range("c" + 50).Top`    '<~~ Top Position for image

Comment: I receive the following error: Runtime Error '13': Type Mismatch and it highlights the following line of code: `T = .Range("c" + 50).Top`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have misunderstood your question.  Instead of the "last used row" you need to find the last row in column "C" that has a shape in it.  This changed code will find the last row with a shape in column C, then it will add 2 rows to that number, and then place the image two rows beneath the lowest one.  You can change those rows to however many you need.  You might get an error if there are no shapes on the sheet when this is run.  If so then you will have to create an error capture for that.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ImgPath As String
Dim W As Double, H As Double
Dim L As Long, T As Long
Dim myArr() As Variant, myArrCounter As Long
Dim newRowNumb As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mobile POS Log Sheet")

'////////////////////////////////////////   This section will find the row of the bottom most shape in Column C
ReDim myArr(1 To 1)
myArrCounter = 0

For Each wshape In ws.Shapes
    myArrCounter = myArrCounter + 1
    If myArrCounter = 1 And wshape.TopLeftCell.Column = 3 Then
        myArr(myArrCounter) = wshape.TopLeftCell.row
    Else:
        If wshape.TopLeftCell.Column = 3 And wshape.TopLeftCell.row > myArr(UBound(myArr)) Then
            ReDim Preserve myArr(1 To myArrCounter)
            myArr(myArrCounter) = wshape.TopLeftCell.row
        End If
    End If
Next wshape
newRowNumb = myArr(UBound(myArr)) + 2 ' this adds two rows to place the new picure.  Change the "2" to how many rows you need



'~~> This is my current pic file path
ImgPath = "C:\Users\raphaelo\Downloads\test.gif"


    With ws
        W = 30                  '<~~ Width
        H = 11                  '<~~ Height
        L = .Range("c" & newRowNumb).Left   '<~~ This is what should be changing each time I run the command
        T = .Range("c" & newRowNumb).Top    '<~~ This is what should be changing each time I run the command
         '<~~ Both the L and T Range entries should change to the next cell (C3 to C4 to C5 and so on) One digit up every time I run the Command Code
         '<~~ Unless it's the Placement entry below?
        With .Pictures.Insert(ImgPath)
            With .ShapeRange
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Width = W
                .Height = H
            End With
            .Left = L
            .Top = T
            .Placement = 1 '<~~ Not sure if this is the one that should change one digit up each time I run the Command instead?
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! this is the closest it is gotten to work! sometimes it works and when I change to `newRowNumb = myArr(UBound(myArr)) + 1` it pastes in same cell. Then If I change it back to `+2` it works and if I change it back to `+1` for about three or four tries it goes back to pasting on same cell. (so it seems to only work with the `+2` code that you originally gave me). Also sometimes even if there is an object already in place it gives me a 
Runtime Error 1004:
Object defined or Application defined Error.
on this code:
`If myArrCounter = 1 And wshape.TopLeftCell.Column = 3 Then`

Comment: Am I doing something wrong?  Ideally like I mentioned on my initial post the first InkPicture should insert on column 3 row 3 and go down from there but this code starts at row 1 is there a workaround this?

Comment: I really appreciate this!

Comment: Don't know if this has anything to do with this but in the same sheet Rows 1 and 2 are Locked/fixed headers and Columns 1,2,4,5,6,7 have other different formulas that are meant to create other calculations (none of these interact or utilize or reference column C for anything) but figured I should share just in case.

Comment: While in Debug of the highlighted code it recognizes the `myArrCounter = 1` and returns a positive count but then it says that `wshape.TopLeftCell.Column = 3` returns this: , _<Subscript out of Range>_